# ggplot: plot results of factor analysis in a different way

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am interested in plotting the results of factor analysis, I assume I can do it with ggplot, however, due to the lack of experience, I do not even know which function I need.
Let's say the final plot should have all the factors plotted cumulatively in separate boxes attached to each other. On the y-axis I have loadings. The outcome example is here (*Image from Reiman et al, 2002*):

[image]

Here, I have the generated factor analysis results and I would like to plot then as on the picture above. What function or combinations of function in ggplot I should use to get plot as above?

`Factor1     Factor2     Factor3      Factor4 
a   0.40351882  0.04890111  0.06699149 -0.011337790
b   0.56224971  0.16761412  0.12377914 -0.002267180
c   -0.06479995 -0.12783615  0.27600629 -0.065118869
d   0.45316391  0.10105420  0.27179360  0.002680849
e  -0.22527711 -0.19788244  0.18876382 -0.020145060
f  -0.18423600 -0.14555464 -0.06755873 -0.450922402
g   0.77175089  0.20664507  0.09714112  0.156988271
h   0.84049526  0.36817776 -0.09346554  0.248800578
i   0.01176635 -0.02680680  0.08637877  0.074280863`

Answer (score 0):

The example plot can be made by function loadplot() from a package StatDA.
Documentation is here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/StatDA/StatDA.pdf